# Installing Python Google Assistant SDK Backtracks to Unusable Older Version

Tags: python-3.x, windows, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to install Google Assistant SDK on Windows following instructions at: 
https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/tree/master/google-assistant-sdk

It looks like some requirement not being satisfied is causing the installation to backtrack to version 0.3.3. Install log is pasted below. Can someone help me debug this?

Using command: 
`pip install --upgrade google-assistant-sdk[samples]`

Ouput:

```
Requirement already satisfied: google-assistant-sdk[samples] in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (0.6.0)

Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib>=0.1.0 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (0.1.0)

Collecting google-assistant-grpc==0.2.1 (from google-assistant-sdk[samples])

Using cached google_assistant_grpc-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.6 kB)

Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<2,>=1.21 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from urllib3[secure]<2,>=1.21; extra == "samples"->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (1.21.1)

Requirement already satisfied: sounddevice<0.4,>=0.3.7 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (0.3.7)

Requirement already satisfied: click<7,>=6.7 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (6.7)

Requirement already satisfied: tenacity<5,>=4.1.0 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (4.1.0)

INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of google-assistant-sdk[samples] to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.

Collecting google-assistant-sdk[samples]

Using cached google_assistant_sdk-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.0 kB)

Using cached google_assistant_sdk-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.6 kB)

Using cached google_assistant_sdk-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.6 kB)

Collecting google-assistant-grpc==0.2.0 (from google-assistant-sdk[samples])

Using cached google_assistant_grpc-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.6 kB)

Collecting google-assistant-sdk[samples]

Using cached google_assistant_sdk-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.0 kB)

Collecting google-assistant-grpc==0.1.0 (from google-assistant-sdk[samples])

Using cached google_assistant_grpc-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.2 kB)

INFO: pip is still looking at multiple versions of google-assistant-sdk[samples] to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.

Collecting google-assistant-sdk[samples]

Using cached google_assistant_sdk-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.0 kB)

Using cached google_assistant_sdk-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.9 kB)

INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. See https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/backtracking for guidance. If you want to abort this run, press Ctrl + C.

Using cached google_assistant_sdk-0.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.9 kB)

Using cached google_assistant_sdk-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.9 kB)

Using cached google_assistant_sdk-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)

Collecting google-assistant-grpc==0.0.2 (from google-assistant-sdk[samples])

Using cached google_assistant_grpc-0.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.2 kB)

Requirement already satisfied: googleapis-common-protos>=1.5.2 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from google-assistant-grpc==0.0.2->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (1.63.0)

Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.3.5 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from google-assistant-grpc==0.0.2->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (1.62.1)

Requirement already satisfied: google-auth in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib>=0.1.0->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (2.29.0)

Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib>=0.1.0->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (2.0.0)

Requirement already satisfied: CFFI>=1.0 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from sounddevice<0.4,>=0.3.7->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (1.16.0)

Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from tenacity<5,>=4.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (1.16.0)

Requirement already satisfied: monotonic>=0.6 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from tenacity<5,>=4.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (1.6)

Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from urllib3[secure]<2,>=1.21; extra == "samples"->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (2024.2.2)

Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from CFFI>=1.0->sounddevice<0.4,>=0.3.7->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (2.21)

Requirement already satisfied: protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0.dev0,>=3.19.5 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from googleapis-common-protos>=1.5.2->google-assistant-grpc==0.0.2->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (3.20.3)

Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib>=0.1.0->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (3.2.2)

Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.0.0 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib>=0.1.0->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (2.31.0)

Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from google-auth->google-auth-oauthlib>=0.1.0->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (5.3.3)

Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from google-auth->google-auth-oauthlib>=0.1.0->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (0.4.0)

Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from google-auth->google-auth-oauthlib>=0.1.0->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (4.9)

Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.7.0,>=0.4.6 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth->google-auth-oauthlib>=0.1.0->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (0.6.0)

Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.0.0->requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib>=0.1.0->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (3.3.2)

Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.0.0->requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib>=0.1.0->google-auth-oauthlib[tool]>=0.1.0->google-assistant-sdk[samples]) (3.6)

Using cached google_assistant_grpc-0.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)

Using cached google_assistant_sdk-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)

Installing collected packages: google-assistant-grpc, google-assistant-sdk

Attempting uninstall: google-assistant-grpc

Found existing installation: google-assistant-grpc 0.3.0

Uninstalling google-assistant-grpc-0.3.0:

Successfully uninstalled google-assistant-grpc-0.3.0

Attempting uninstall: google-assistant-sdk

Found existing installation: google-assistant-sdk 0.6.0

Uninstalling google-assistant-sdk-0.6.0:

Successfully uninstalled google-assistant-sdk-0.6.0

Successfully installed google-assistant-grpc-0.0.2 google-assistant-sdk-0.3.3
```